# How to write post in curl

Tags: post, curl

I need to execute the information below on my terminal. Can anyone please tell me how to write this in curl?

```
POST /shopgate/api.php HTTP/1.1         
User-Agent: Shopgate     
Host: ihrshop.com     
Accept: */*     
X-Shopgate-Auth-User: 12345-1329146130     
X-Shopgate-Auth-Token: 07c573bcaf4e1b4669c3dd23175d78fcfab4e5b4     
Content-Length: 80     
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear. But, I'm providing you with some good answer that might help you.

If you want to send data through `POST`, then you can use this.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

`$post` will be the fields you want to send.

if you want the headers' info

```
POST /shopgate/api.php HTTP/1.1         
User-Agent: Shopgate     
Host: ihrshop.com     
Accept: */*     
X-Shopgate-Auth-User: 12345-1329146130     
X-Shopgate-Auth-Token: 07c573bcaf4e1b4669c3dd23175d78fcfab4e5b4     
Content-Length: 80     
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

then you better need to state it.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
```

`$header` is BOOLEAN value to get this info or not.

If you need more help, I'll be happy :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I basically have to authenticate myself to use someone's api as mentioned in this website http://wiki.shopgate.com/Plugin_API_authentication.
Therefore this is the header for the request.
What i could come up till now was to translate it like this into curl   
_curl -v -X POST -d api.php http://shopgate/api.php -H "User-Agent: Shopgate" -H "Host: xxxx" -H "Accept */*" -H "X-Shopgate-Auth-User: xxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-Shopgate-Auth-Tokenclear: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Length: 80" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"_                 
but it still doesnt work!!!

Comment: @user2587123 well, your question's answer is right away on the page you gave reference to under the heading "Testing the Authentication".

Answer (score 1):

curl has a `--header` option.
`man curl` has the details.

Comment: Thank you but i still dont know how to convert this header into curl syntax on the terminal. This is what i have come up with till now
_curl -v -X POST -d api.php shopgate/api.php -H "User-Agent: Shopgate" -H "Host: xxxx" -H "Accept */*" -H "X-Shopgate-Auth-User: xxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-Shopgate-Auth-Tokenclear: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Length: 80" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"_

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-H "Accept: */*"`